# Find the indefinite integral $\int\frac{(x+1)e^x}{x(1+xe^x)}dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, indefinite-integrals

Find the indefinite integral

$$\int\frac{(x+1)e^x}{x(1+xe^x)}dx$$

I feel like this function does not have an anti-derivative in the form of elementary functions.

Comment: So no one else has to try typing it in... Wolfram Alpha doesn't find anything.

Comment: @Katoyu, I think, the multiplicand  $x$ in the denominator is a typo as $$\frac{d(1+xe^x)}{dx}=(x+1)e^x$$

Answer (score 3):

You're entirely correct that the *posted problem* has no elementary antiderivative; you can easily confirm this using [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%20%28%28x%2b1%29e%5Ex%29/%28x%281%2bxe%5Ex%29%29dx).

However, if perchance your problem has a typo in it, and you meant to post:

$$\int\frac{(x+1)e^x}{(1+xe^x)}dx$$

Then note that with

- $\;u = 1 + xe^x,\;$
- $\;du = xe^x + e^x = (x+1)e^x$,

  thus giving us an integral of the form $$\int \dfrac {du}{u} = \ln |u| + C = \ln|1 + xe^x| + C$$

Answer (score 2):

You're right: Maple confirms that it does not have an elementary antiderivative.

Answer (score 0):

As written, you're correct. However, I suspect that it is supposed to be $$\int\frac{(x+1)e^x}{1+xe^x}\,dx,$$ which *does* have a nice antiderivative family, as the numerator is the derivative of the denominator.